# Regex \p{Cs} not matching symbol in Java 16

Tags: java, regex, java-11, java-16

Does anyone know why the regex `\p{Cs}` does not match the symbol  in Java 16?
It used to match it in Java 11.

Java 11

```
jshell 
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.7
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import java.util.regex.*

jshell> var text = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(55622).appendCodePoint(56380)
text ==> 

jshell> Pattern.compile("\\p{Cs}").matcher(text).find()
$3 ==> true
```

Java 16

```
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 16.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import java.util.regex.*

jshell> var text = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(55622).appendCodePoint(56380)
text ==> 

jshell> Pattern.compile("\\p{Cs}").matcher(text).find()
$3 ==> false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your “symbol ” has the codepoint 399420, which is not assigned by the Unicode standard (yet), so if you are seeing something useful here, it’s a non-standard behavior of your system.

The way you construct the string, is not correct, semantically, but happens to create the intended string. For historic reasons, Java’s API is centered around a UTF-16 representation.

When you define the symbol using two surrogate characters, i.e.

```
var text = "\uD946\uDC3C";
System.out.println(text.codePointAt(0));
```

you’ll get

```
399420
```

On the other hand, when you use

```java
var text = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(399420);
text.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.printf("\\u%04X", c));
System.out.println();
```

you’ll get

```
\uD946\uDC3C
```

In other words, the sequence of the two surrogate UTF-16 `char` units `\uD946`, `\uDC3C` is equivalent to the single codepoint `399420`. Conceptionally, the string consists of the single codepoint, in other words,

```java
System.out.println(text.codePointCount(0, text.length()) + " codepoint(s)");
System.out.println(text.codePointAt(0));
System.out.println("type " + Character.getType(text.codePointAt(0)));
```

will print

```
1 codepoint(s)
399420
type 0
```

in either case. The type `0` indicates that this codepoint is unassigned.

You are using `appendCodePoint` for appending two UTF-16 units to the `StringBuilder`, but since this method treats codepoints of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) the same way as UTF-16 units, it happens to construct the same string, too.

Since the category of the codepoint is “unassigned”, it shouldn’t be “surrogate”, so `\p{Cs}` should never find a match here. When processing a valid Unicode string, you should never encounter this category, as it can only match dangling surrogate characters which can not be interpreted as a codepoint outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

But there’s the bug [JDK-8247546, Pattern matching does not skip correctly over supplementary characters](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8247546). Before Java 16, the regex engine did process the codepoint at location zero correctly, but advanced only one `char` position, so it found a dangling surrogate character when looking at `char` position `1` alone.

We can verify it using

```java
var m = Pattern.compile("\\p{Cs}").matcher(text);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("found a match at " + m.start());
}
```

which prints “found a match at 1” prior to JDK 16, which is wrong, as position `1` should be skipped when there’s a single codepoint at `char` positions `0` and `1`.

This bug has been fixed in JDK 16. So now, the string is treated as a single codepoint of the “unassigned” category. Of course, this category might change again in the future. But it should never be “surrogate”.

Comment: I see.

I don't really construct the String with: `var text = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(55622).appendCodePoint(56380)`. 

I only did that to try to represent the symbol `` which is not being matched by `\\p{Cs}` in Java 16. 

I found this problem in a test case while upgrading a system to Java 16. 

The test matched the character in Java 11, but it doesn't in Java 16. 

I was wondering why.

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: How have you solved the issue? Can we update the regex in a way to continue to work?